# Redirect non-admin after login, and in url - /admin

Tags: admin, user-roles, user-access, wp-login-form

How and where, can i make function, that will redirect user (if it's not admin) to my specific URL? 
(the same - when logged user type /wp-admin URL.)

Answer (score 0):

All functions place in `functions.php` of your theme. And create redirect on `template_redirect` hook.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'make_redirect');
function make_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://google.com' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: `current_user_can()` should not be used to check roles, it checks capabilities: "While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results." https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

Comment: This function work fine if you set role as a parametr.

Comment: Yeah, it "just work", but as the docs say: "this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results". Better check `roles` property of `WP_User` object. For exmaple, `$user = wp_get_current_user()` and then `if( in_array( "administrator", (array) $user->roles )